# flutter sign out button not working with routename

Tags: flutter, logout

I add sign out button but when I press that button it show me this errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph1Bs.png)

maybe because I add routeName in login page!!

can any one explain the error for me??

this is my code:

```
 ListTile(
          title: const Text('Logout'),
            trailing: const Icon(
              Icons.logout_rounded,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            onTap: () async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushReplacementNamed(LoginScreen.routeName);
            }),
```

this is my loginscreen:

```
import 'package:test/page/loginForm.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
static const routeName = '/login';
const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final theme = Theme.of(context);

return Scaffold(

  body: Stack(

    children: [

      SizedBox(

        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/Login.jpeg",
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 400,
          right: 60,
          left: 60,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              LoginForm(),
```

Comment: probably you didn't define LoginScreen.routeName in route generator

Comment: I added routeName in login screen << static const routeName = '/login';

Comment: Can you post your full MaterialApp declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

Most times it's because you did something wrong in main, or you defined a route incorrectly. if nothing helps, try these steps:

[image]

Ensure both initial route and onGenerate routes are correct.

[image]

This class is a magic string for routes. it allows you to not type strings when calling images or route etc. these will be used when navigating to a page etc.

[image]

Ensure you're calling the right page in your routes. [image]

Lastly, we navigate just as you'd do from login page to homepage or vice versa.

Hope this helps you in anyway.